# How to import a file in R and give it a name

Tags: r

I have a R class which looks like below

```
source("data_validation.R")

data_validation.mymodel <- function(mymodel,newdata=list()) {

  data_validation(newdata)
}
```

I have a function called `data_validation` in which I need to call another function from another file which I'm sourcing with the same name. But it's giving me an error and can't find the function in the other file because it has the same name. How can I have an alias for my functions in the `data_validation.R` file so I can easily distinguish these 2 functions (i.e. something similar to python where I can say import data_validation as dv)

Comment: *"function from another file ... with the same name"* is not going to happen unless they are loaded into different namespaces/environments. The reason one can differentiate between between (e.g.) `lag` from packages `stats` and `dplyr` is via double-colon reference: `stats::lag` versus `dplyr::lag`. If a function with the same name is loaded into a namespace, the old version in that namespace is over-written, every time.

Comment: double colon only works for packages, not file that I'm importing using source, is that right?

Comment: Yes, which is why `source`ing from files isn't giving you that opportunity to *not* overwrite on loading the second.

Comment: so there is no option in this case?

Comment: I have looked several times for solutions to mimic python's `import pandas as pd`, and nothing abounds.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you:

1. Must `source` the files, vice making at least one of them a formal package; and
2. Cannot change the function name of *either* function defined in those sourced files,

you will have to work around things to be able to use both functions.

Here's a hack that might work for you.

1. I'm starting with a simple file, `foo.R`, that merely defines one function:

   ```r
   myfunc <- function(x) x+1
   ```
2. In the global environment, I'll load and test it:

   ```r
   source("~/Downloads/foo.R")
   myfunc(2)
   # [1] 3
   ```
3. But let's say I have another file (`foo2.R`) with the same function:

   ```r
   myfunc <- function(x) x+1000
   ```
4. Let's write a wrapper around source that looks for just that function:

   ```r
   wrap_source <- function(...) { source(..., local = TRUE); environment(); }

   ls(envir=wrap_source("~/Downloads/foo2.R"))
   # [1] "myfunc"

   other <- wrap_source("~/Downloads/foo2.R")
   myfunc(1)
   # [1] 2
   other$myfunc(1)
   # [1] 1001
   ```

Comment: Any thoughts, HHH? I understand that this doesn't really solve your immediate problem, but I don't know of any construct that allows this without involving explicit module/package-like namespaces.